# Displaying multiple screens based on ternary condition in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, conditional-operator

I have a scenario where I am showing a spinner when a page loads and while it's loading, it fetches some data in DB and sets a bool value to either true or false based on data availability.

I then want to share either screen A or B based on the boolean result.

I have done the following in my code but the app keeps showing the spinner. Any ideas what I might be doing incorrectly?

```
return _isLoading? 
      Center(child:Loading(),):
     _isPersonalInfoSubmitted?ScreenA():ScreenB();
```

**Second Attempt (Using Future Builder)**
I want to show categories if the loggedin user is an admin. Else, for the rest of the users, I want to fetch address of the user from the DB. If the address is null, show Personal Details Screen else show Categories.

```
  return FutureBuilder  (
      future: userId=='ADMIN_ID'?
               Provider.of<Categories>(context,listen:false).fetchAndReturnCategories(): 
               Provider.of<Addresses>(context,listen: false).fetchAndReturnAddress(userId)!=null?
               Provider.of<Categories>(context,listen:false).fetchAndReturnCategories():null,
       builder: (context, snap) {
                 inspect(snap);
                  if (snap.hasData) {
                     var categoriesData =   Provider.of<Categories>(context);
                    return  snap.hasData?
                        Scaffold(...) : PersonalDetails();
```

What happens here is that the method `fetchAndReturnCategories` gets executed even if the userID is not admin id. Do I have the correct setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prefer to use FutureBuilder

```dart
FutureBuilder<SomeClass>(
                future: fetchdatFuture,
                builder: (ctx, snap) {
                  if (snap.hasData) {
                    return  snap.data?ScreenA():ScreenB();
                  } else if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) 
                   {
                    return Center(child:Loading());
                  }
                  return Text("Error");
                },
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed the setState to rebuild your widget

```
var bool _isLoading = true;

return _isLoading? 
      Center(child:Loading(),):
     _isPersonalInfoSubmitted?ScreenA():ScreenB();

void _apiCall() {
  // After Success of API Call
  setState((){
     _isLoading = false;
  }) 
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dharmik, this was indeed the case. But even after implementing this solution, it was honestly messy and slow. I am trying to re-do the whole thing with futurebuilder. I have updated my solution. Please advice me how to approach this.